# Session Variable Not Returning

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have this PHP code that writes some query values into an excel spreadsheet, using some variables created by a PHP session.

```
<?php
session_start();

error_reporting(0);
require_once("config.php");

require_once('new_stuff/php-excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$link = mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass)
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$sdate = $_SESSION['startdate'];
$edate = $_SESSION['enddate'];

//$sdate = $_POST['startdate'];
list($smonth, $sday, $syear) = split('[/.-]', $sdate);

//$edate = $_POST['enddate'];
list($emonth, $eday, $eyear) = split('[/.-]', $edate);


mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Could not select database');

// Performing SQL query
$query = 
    'SELECT 
        mantis_category_table.name, 
        mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y") AS DATE2, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified), "%m-%d-%Y") AS FirstOfdate_modified,
        ROUND((min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified)- mantis_bug_table.date_submitted)/ 86400, 1) as day_difference
    FROM (mantis_bug_table INNER JOIN mantis_bug_history_table 
    ON 
        mantis_bug_table.id = mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id) 
    INNER JOIN 
        mantis_category_table ON mantis_bug_table.category_id = mantis_category_table.id 
    WHERE
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%Y-%m-%d")
            BETWEEN DATE("'.$syear.'-'.$smonth.'-'.$sday.'") AND DATE("'.$eyear.'-'.$emonth.'-'.$eday.'")
    GROUP BY 
        mantis_category_table.name, mantis_bug_table.category_id, mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, mantis_bug_table.status, mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id, mantis_bug_history_table.field_name, mantis_bug_history_table.new_value 
    HAVING 
        (((mantis_bug_table.status)<>90) AND ((mantis_bug_history_table.field_name)="status") AND ((mantis_bug_history_table.new_value)="50")) 
    ORDER BY 
        mantis_category_table.name, FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m")';

echo $query;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

When I echo the query, I am seeing that the startdate is not being passed to the page, even though it's written exactly the same was as enddate, which is showing up.

Can someone point out the flaw in my session variable gathering technique?

Comment: have you set startdate in the session

Comment: @OliSoproniB - I thought I was, in line 12?

Comment: $sdate = $_SESSION['startdate']; doesnt mean anything if  $_SESSION['startdate'] is empty it would show $sdate as empty too. where is the code that sets a value in $_SESSION['startdate']

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['startdate'] = date('Y-m-d');

$_SESSION['enddate'] = date('Y-m-d');


$sdate = $_SESSION['startdate'];

$edate = $_SESSION['enddate'];

$sday = date('d', strtotime($sdate));

$smonth = date('m', strtotime($sdate));

$syear = date('Y', strtotime($sdate));



$eday = date('d', strtotime($edate));

$emonth = date('m', strtotime($edate));

$eyear = date('Y', strtotime($edate));



$query = 
    'SELECT 
        mantis_category_table.name, 
        mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y") AS DATE2, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified), "%m-%d-%Y") AS FirstOfdate_modified,
        ROUND((min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified)- mantis_bug_table.date_submitted)/ 86400, 1) as day_difference
    FROM (mantis_bug_table INNER JOIN mantis_bug_history_table 
    ON 
        mantis_bug_table.id = mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id) 
    INNER JOIN 
        mantis_category_table ON mantis_bug_table.category_id = mantis_category_table.id 
    WHERE
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%Y-%m-%d")
            BETWEEN DATE("'.$syear.'-'.$smonth.'-'.$sday.'") AND DATE("'.$eyear.'-'.$emonth.'-'.$eday.'")
    GROUP BY 
        mantis_category_table.name, mantis_bug_table.category_id, mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, mantis_bug_table.status, mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id, mantis_bug_history_table.field_name, mantis_bug_history_table.new_value 
    HAVING 
        (((mantis_bug_table.status)<>90) AND ((mantis_bug_history_table.field_name)="status") AND ((mantis_bug_history_table.new_value)="50")) 
    ORDER BY 
        mantis_category_table.name, FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m")';

echo $query;
```

Comment: When I `print_r` it, it shows up. I am not sure why it doesn't show up in the query...

Comment: try that up, you need to set the end date properly so that they would not have the same value with start date